# "We all are planning" vs. "We are all planning"

Tags: sentence-construction

> We **all are** planning to attend this party.

OR

> We **are all** planning to attend this party.

I'd like to say, that I and another persons are going to attend some party.

Also how to add a refinement to this "all"?

> We all **with (or "and") another invited persons** are planning to attend this party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

> We all are planning to attend this party.

and

> We are all planning to attend this party.

work.

For the extended sentence, some context is needed.

> We all, with (or "and") other invited guests, are planning to attend this party.

would be fine if "We all" referred to a group that the person this sentence is spoken towards knows as a group (otherwise the 'we' does not work), and some other persons were also coming specifically with this group

> We all and another invited person are planning to attend this party.

Would be fine if just one other person went with that one group specifically (the whole party my be attended by more people).

Just to be sure: If the 'other' invited guests referred to the (implicitly or explicitly) invited spouses of the guests,

> We all, and our plus-ones, are planning to attend this party.

would be ok.

Comment: bukwyrm, just what I sought. Ok, no matter where is "all". And "other" for persons and "another" for one person. If "all" after "are" then is this correct: We are all, and our plus-ones, planning to attend this party.

Comment: bukwyrm, and, at last,  can I use "everybody" instead of "all"?

Comment: For your first sentence: here you just moved the 'are' to the front - this makes the sentence awkward and borderline ungrammatical. Better use my last sentence from the answer. For your second request: "We everybody, and our..." does not work. ---- "Everybody invited is planning to attend this party" works, though

Comment: @user79871:  *It's no matter where **all** is*.  It does matter where **is** is.   :)

Answer (score 1):

A way to make the sentences you offered above less complicated is to switch them from a passive voice to an active voice.

Example:

- Passive voice: We are all planning to attend this party.
- Active voice: We all plan to attend this party.

With the active voice you can completely shed the verb "to be" and presents a more concise thought.

With the active voice format worrying about where to place the "are" is no longer an issue!

Comment: @J.R. how do I "accept" your edits? (P.s. thank you!)

Comment: No need to accept them; edits can be rolled back, but they don't need to be explicitly accepted. You can read more about edits on [this page of our help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Welcome to ELL, and we look forward to reading your next post!